# Why this code convert value to double instead to float?

Tags: java, object, constructor

I got a question. Why this code prints YYZ10.0 instead of printing XXZ10.0?
The first constructor is A(int), then inside statement it returns false, so 9+1f should jump into A(float) constructor but instead it is going to A(double).

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(new A(011).fun()[1]);
    }
}

class A{
    double value;
    public A(int value){
        this(value >> 2 == 1 ? value+1.0 : value+1f);
    }
    public A(float value){
        System.out.print("XX");
        this.value = value;
    }
    public A(double value){
        System.out.print("YY");
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Object[] fun(){
        return new Object[]{new Object(), this};
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Z"+value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `double value` is a double and will not automatically change to a float just because you add a float to it with `+1f`.

Comment: But when I am changing double value to float value i am getting an error: ossible lossy conversion from double to float, so I think it is still going to double constructor.

Comment: Both possible results of a ternary expression must have the same type.  What you are trying to do where in some cases the result will be a float and in other cases it will be a double is not possible. The result of your ternary operator will either always be a float or always be a double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are multiple overloads of a method, Java picks which one to call at compile time, not at run time. In this case, you're calling the constructor via `this`. At compile time, Java decides which of the three constructors to call, and you can see that it's going to have to be the one that accepts a `double`.

Java has to choose the constructor that accepts a `double` not just because it can handle both the `double` and `float` cases, but also because there is no `float` case. The ternary expression can only have one type. It's not `double` sometimes and `float` sometimes; it's always `double`.

Consider this statement:

```
____ result = value >> 2 == 1 ? value+1.0 : value+1f;
```

What type would you put in the blank? There's no way to write "sometimes `double`, sometimes `float`." It's going to have to be `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line (in the `A(int)` constructor):

```
this(value >> 2 == 1 ? value+1.0 : value+1f);
```

To this:

```
this(value >> 2 == 1 ? value+1f : value+1f);
```

It should call the correct constructor that way.

Comment: Ok, but anyway why does it still try to use A(double) constructor when 011>>2 (9 >> 2 = 2) and the statement is false.

Comment: It's just like you would try to make a method return a `float` and a `double` in different cases. The ternary operator automatically casts the `float` to a `double` because it can't return `float` in one case and `double` in another case.